# Flyby anomaly observations: the Pluto case

Tags: orbital-motion, rocket-science, celestial-mechanics, space-mission

Recently, the [flyby anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyby_anomaly) was [back in the Juno probe](https://www.universetoday.com/137984/juno-isnt-exactly-supposed-flyby-anomaly-back-happen/). I was wondering if the New Horizons probe also observed it. Any references for the New Horizons probe? Any idea if New Horizons could test it on MU69 in a year or so?

Comment: I thought that Juno did *not* observe the flyby anomaly in Jupiter? It seems that you're saying it did observe it; if that is the case, could you provide a reference saying it was obsserved?

Comment: It is done. I was surprised since I thought the flyby is was weird...Anyway it seems it is not a measurement systematics, since it is observed from independent methods...So I become curious and curious about this thing...